# Scala: expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type

Tags: scala, generics, types

```
trait Ingredient{}

case class Papperoni() extends Ingredient{}
case class Mushroom() extends Ingredient{}

trait ToppingDef[T] {
}

object PepperoniDef extends Serializable with ToppingDef[Papperoni] {
}

object MushroomDef extends Serializable with ToppingDef[Mushroom] {
}

class Oven[T <: Ingredient](val topping:ToppingDef[T]) {
}

class Pizza {
  def cook = {
    val topping =
      if(someCondition()) { PepperoniDef }
      else { MushroomDef}

    new Oven(topping) // <-- build error here
  }
}
```

I am using Scala 2.11.  This example is somewhat contrived but I’ve stripped out everything unrelated to the problem to provide a concise example.

The error I get on the last line is:

```
Error:(26, 5) no type parameters for constructor Oven: (topping: ToppingDef[T])Oven[T] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Serializable with ToppingDef[_ >: Papperoni with Mushroom <: Product with Serializable with Ingredient])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Serializable with ToppingDef[_ >: Papperoni with Mushroom <: Product with Serializable with Ingredient]
 required: ToppingDef[?T]
    new Oven(topping)
```

However changing the last line to this for example:

```
new Oven(PepperoniDef)
```

builds fine.  So the compiler has no problem finding the type when the parameter is passed explicitly like this.

Also, removing the `Serializable` trait from `PepperoniDef` and `MushroomDef` like this:

```
object PepperoniDef extends ToppingDef[Papperoni] {
}

object MushroomDef extends ToppingDef[Mushroom] {
}
```

also builds. However in my case I need the Serializable.

I think I can probably restructure the code to work around this if necessary but I would like to understand what's going on, I don't know why the type is ambiguous in the first case, or why the presence of the Serializable trait has any effect.  Thanks in advance for any insights.

EDIT: Thank you for the replies, very helpful.  I think the most concise fix is to change this:

```
val topping =
```

to this:

```
val topping:ToppingDef[_ <: Ingredient] =
```

Which cures the build error and does not require a change to the generic classes, which I would like to keep as simple an unannotated as possible so as to have Scala infer as much type information as possible.

This doesn't answer the question of why the presence of `Serializable` has any effect on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that helping the compiler out with type annotation makes this compile:

```
val topping: ToppingDef[
    _ >: Papperoni with Mushroom <: Ingredient with Product with Serializable] =
    if (true) {
      PepperoniDef
    } else {
      MushroomDef
    }
```

I don't think this has to do with the `Serializable` class specifically, it seems like a compiler quirk to me since the produced type has a mixed in type including `Product with Serializable` anyway.

You can also "relax" the type signature by making `T` covariant, meaning `Topping[Ingredient]` will be inferred. This happens because the "is subtype of" relation `Papperoni <: Ingredient` on a covariant `ToppingDef[+T]` means `ToppingDef[Papperoni] <: ToppingDef[Ingredient]`, thus allowing the common supertype for `T`:

```
trait ToppingDef[+T]
val topping: ToppingDef[Ingredient with Product with Serializable] =
  if (true) {
    PepperoniDef
  } else {
    MushroomDef
  }
```

And this also compiles without type annotation.

Edit:

Making `Oven`s type parameter an existential instead of a universally quantified type seems to work as well with the `Serializable` trait:

```
class Oven[_ <: Ingredient](val topping: ToppingDef[_])

val topping: Serializable with ToppingDef[_ <: Ingredient] =
  if (true) {
    PepperoniDef
  } else {
    MushroomDef
  }

new Oven(topping)
```

Comment: The real question is - why does the inferred type (which can be simplified to `Serializable with ToppingDef[_ <: Ingredient]`) not satisfy `ToppingDef[T]` for any `T <: Ingredient`? If you set the type of `topping` to `Serializable with ToppingDef[_ <: Ingredient]` you get the same error, if you set it to `ToppingDef[_ <: Ingredient]` - it works. Can't say why... can you?

Comment: @TzachZohar Going through the spec.

Comment: @TzachZohar Nothing in the spec, I looked at `-Ytyper-debug` output but nothing informative came out. Smells like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some type information to your trait:

```
trait ToppingDef[+T <: Ingredient] {}
```

Right now the `topping` variable is not able to figure out that `T` is supposed to be an `Ingredient` so you need to tell it.

Comment: that one workaround - but it's actually not necessary and it doesn't explain why removing the `extends Serializable` from the objects also compiles...

Comment: Thank you.  Can you comment on why [+T <: Ingredient] fixes the build error, but [T <: Ingredient] does not?

Comment: The `+` denotes covariance, you can read more about it in the docs, they have some examples: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html